# Making UIButton corners appear more 'round'

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

Does anyone actually know how to make this button's corners appear SMOOTHLY round?
It's not that bad at the moment, but it could be better.

I made them as they are now, by writing single line of code (it's on the photo, at the bottom).

Anyone?

The code that makes button 'roundish' (as requested):

```
// Making the addEventButton 'roundish'
addEventButton.layer.cornerRadius = addEventButton.bounds.size.height / 2.0
```

[image]

Comment: Please, do not post images of code. Please [edit] your question and replace the image of your code with your actual code, copy and pasted as text. Images can't be search or referenced and they are much harder to read.

Comment: To change the 'roundness' of the use an asset as the background.

Comment: What the heck is more round than `cornerRadius = height/2`????

Answer (score 3):

You could always create the image itself in Photoshop or Illustrator, then set it as the button's image. That's what I tend to do on certain occasions.

Comment: Yep this is probably the best approach as otherwise unless of course you want to attempt to subclass the UIButton and do your own custom drawing which might look better but it's a lot of work.

Comment: I actually tried to do it 'programatically only', but it seems to be the best approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is defining a `User Defined Runtime Attributes`in IBuilder
set `layer.cornerRadius as Number with value 35` (or what you want)

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bg2fB.png)

and voila [The Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Era6R.png)

Comment: That's no different to setting it in code and the issue you have here is if auto layout or something changes the size of the button it may be incorrect something which can only be fixed by setting it in the code.  The issue here is not setting the radius it's that the person doesn't think it looks round enough.

Comment: then I misunderstood, the only solution for this is use a image background with alpha value

Answer (score 0):

You can easily set based on storyboard can't required any coding.

If you prefer to work in Storyboards, there's another option.

First, set the width and height to be the same value to make a perfect square. 
[image]

Second, type in the following attributes. IMPORTANT- make the value of your layer.cornerRadius half the size of your width. 
[image]

Then, when you run the app, your button will be round. 
[image]

You can set height and width based on your requirements.

Thanks.